# What is the `yank` command in XCode?

Tags: mac, xcode, yank

In XCode there's a text key binding ^Y to the "yank" command.

What does "yank" mean?  I thought it was to "yank back deleted text" but so far it only "yanks back" text I **cut**, which means its synonymous with "paste" on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yanking and pasting are different terms for the same thing.  I first learned about it through pico, and it seems that emacs uses the term as well:

http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/gnu-info/emacs_13.html#SEC59

Answer (score 3):

Yank inserts the most recent block of text from the kill buffer, which is the CLI equivalent of a clipboard.

Some ways the kill ring is different from the clipboard on OS X:

- For example <kbd>⌃K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd> and <kbd>⌧</kbd> add the deleted text to the kill ring
- Copied text is not added to the kill ring
- It can only contain plain text

  - Yank acts like paste and match style in rich text views
- Pressing <kbd>⌃K</kbd> multiple times in a row appends all deleted ranges into a single block

Comment: Does Xcode use a kill ring instead of the clipboard when using Yank in Xcode? Are they integrated or independent?

Comment: Text fields in Xcode behave like standard text views in most cases, so the kill ring is independent from the clipboard. (Even though ⌘X adds the deleted text to both.)